# Can't access SQL db inside Docker container

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, docker, mariadb

I have a SQL db running successfully. However, I cannot access it in my SQL client.

```
docker run -it --name sql_key_container -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=testpw -e MYSQL_DATABASE=key_volume -p 3306:3306 -d myimgname/ubuntumaria:0.2
```

I verified it's running by `docker exec fcd12bf1da81 /etc/init.d/mysql status`

I mapped 3306 -> 3306 and using the host IP. Still getting a timeout. What could this be?

Comment: Have you tried adding `--net=host` option to `docker run`?

Answer (score 0):

You have now a database in container `fcd12bf1da81` running, listening on its local IP and on the host IP on port 3306.

If you want your new container `sql_key_container` to access that database, then the container needs access to `fcd12bf1da81`.

You need to `--link`:

```
docker run -it --link fcd12bf1da81:mydb --name sql_key_container -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=testpw -e MYSQL_DATABASE=key_volume -p 3306:3306 -d myimgname/ubuntumaria:0.2
```

and now you can access the db inside that container with `mydb:3306`.

Comment: Not even another container, just my local machine

Comment: Same problem then. `localhost` is `127.0.0.1` on your local host, but not in your container. You need to make sure that your mysql listens on 0.0.0.0 and you need to give the container the IP address from your host on the network, that the container can access, too. `localhost` inside a container is the interface inside the container, for all ports and services that you do not publish to the outside...